# Mysqli_query result to variable PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've tried looking around and couldn't find an answer myself, so I'll post my problem instead, maybe it will help other people :)

I'm making a mysql query and getting an array out of it as it's supposed to do, but I want to take my first result out of this array and put that result in a variable instead so I can use it in my logic.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$value_High = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT MAX(picID) from pictures");
$id = mysqli_data_seek($value_High, 0);
var_dump($id);
```

I've tried some different things, I get a bool out of myqli_data_seek which is not what I want ofc, so I obviously need to use something else, I just don't know what.

Comment: We would normally give a function call an alias - like max_picid, for instance

Comment: I've always been horrible at naming my things haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$id = mysqli_fetch_row($value_High);
```